# Espresso test fails with NoActivityResumedException in GitHub action

Tags: android, kotlin, github-actions, android-espresso

I'm currently writing instrumented tests for my kotlin app with espresso and when testing locally either with an emulator or my phone it works, but when my github action runs them it fails.

I get the same error in all my tests for a fragment (MapFragment) runned trough GitHub actions

> MapFragmentTest > isLinearLayDisplayed[test(AVD) - 11] FAILED
> androidx.test.espresso.NoActivityResumedException: No activities in stage RESUMED. Did you forget to launch the activity. (test.getActivity() or similar)?
> at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)

Here's my GitHub Action:

```
jobs:
  instrumented_test:
    runs-on: macos-12
    timeout-minutes: 60
    strategy:
      matrix:
        api-level: [28, 29, 30]
        target: [google_apis]
    env:
      JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx4g
      HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP: 1
      
    steps:
      - name: Install Haxm
        run: brew install --cask intel-haxm
      
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v3.5.1
        with:
          distribution: 'adopt'
          java-version: '17'
          cache: 'gradle'
      - uses: reactivecircus/android-emulator-runner@v2
        with:
          api-level: ${{ matrix.api-level }}
          target: ${{ matrix.target }}
          disable-animations: false
          script: ./gradlew createDebugAndroidReport
```

These are my tests (they all fail with the same message):

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MapFragmentTest {
    @Test
    fun isLinearLayDisplayed() {
        launchFragmentInContainer<MapFragment>()
        onView(withId(R.id.search_bar_linearLayout)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }

    @Test
    fun isMapInView() {
        launchFragmentInContainer<MapFragment>()
        onView(withId(R.id.map)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }

    @Test
    fun isSearchBarDisplay() {
        launchFragmentInContainer<MapFragment>()
        onView(withId(R.id.search_bar_layout)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }

    @Test
    fun isSearchBarSlideIcDisplay() {
        launchFragmentInContainer<MapFragment>()
        onView(withId(R.id.search_bar_slide_ic)).check(matches(withEffectiveVisibility(Visibility.VISIBLE)))
    }

    @Test
    fun isSearchIcDisplayed() {
        launchFragmentInContainer<MapFragment>()
        onView(withId(R.id.search_ic)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }

    @Test
    fun isFilterIcDisplayed() {
        launchFragmentInContainer<MapFragment>()
        onView(withId(R.id.search_filter)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }

    @Test
    fun isEditTestDisplayed() {
        launchFragmentInContainer<MapFragment>()
        onView(withId(R.id.search_text)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }

    @Test
    fun isEditTestHintRight() {
        launchFragmentInContainer<MapFragment>()
        onView(withId(R.id.search_text)).check(matches(withHint(R.string.search_bar_hint_light)))
    }
}
```

My dependencies version are :

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
debugImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.5.3"
```

I would say there are no problems with my layout, kotlin or gradle files as the app runs fine and the test succeeds in local.

I tried launching the main activity then changing the fragment but got the same error or having lauchFragment have Initial state as RESUMED same error as well.

Do you guys have any idea what causes my test to fail ?